# How to show a JavaScript code when input box is filled

Tags: javascript, php, html, voyager

I have a Laravel application and I want to display the

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="row mb-5">
                      <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                          <label for="">{{__('How to proceed with')}} {{$current_method->name}} {{__('deposits')}} </label>
                          <div  class="alert alert-secondary bg-teal" role="alert">
                              {!! $current_method->how_to !!}
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

when user fills the box. How can I do it? I have given the sample fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/18svz2hc/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code like below:

```
function check() {
      if (document.getElementById('text').value.length) {
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '<div class="clearfix"></div>'+
                    '<div class="row mb-5">'+
                      '<div class="col-lg-12 ">'+
                          '<label for="">{{__('How to proceed with')}} {{$current_method->name}} {{__('deposits')}} </label>'+
                          '<div  class="alert alert-secondary bg-teal" role="alert">'+ {!! $current_method->how_to !!}</div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '';
      }
  }
```

in https://jsfiddle.net/dhoot/cjquesvk/6/

your requirement can also be tested at https://jsfiddle.net/dhoot/cjquesvk/4/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is going to be rendered as expected but the function you asked is the following.

**HTML**

Just pass the argument `event` to your method `check`, so you get access to its value easily.

```html
<label>text :
    <input name="text" id="text" type="text" onkeyup="check(event)" />
</label>
<br>
<span id="message"></span>
```

**Javascript**

Use backticks (`), so you don't need to worry about line breaks.

```js
var check = function (e) {
  var message = document.getElementById('message')

  if (e.target.value) {
    message.innerHTML = `<div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-lg-12 ">
          <label for="">{{__('How to proceed with')}} {{$current_method->name}} {{__('deposits')}}</label>
          <div class="alert alert-secondary bg-teal" role="alert">{!! $current_method->how_to !!}</div>
        </div>
      </div>`
  } else {
    message.innerHTML = ''
  }
}
```